# Number of Occurance in List of Numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have a small problem to solve in vb.net where i have to count number of occurrence of number 1 in numbers 1762728381128911 i did this solutions but i am sure there is more sophisticated way to do this .

```
Public Function CheckOccurance() As Integer
    Dim numbersList As New List(Of String)
    numbersList.Add("1")
    numbersList.Add("7")
    numbersList.Add("6")
    numbersList.Add("2")
    numbersList.Add("7")
    numbersList.Add("2")
    numbersList.Add("8")
    numbersList.Add("3")
    numbersList.Add("8")
    numbersList.Add("1")
    numbersList.Add("1")
    numbersList.Add("2")
    numbersList.Add("8")
    numbersList.Add("9")
    numbersList.Add("1")
    numbersList.Add("1")
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each value In numbersList
        If value.Equals("1") Then count += 1
    Next
    Return count

End Function
```

Comment: C#: `int count = "1762728381128911".Count(c => c == '1');` just a *Linq* on the initial string.

Comment: i need this in vb.net

Comment: Instead of adding to your list in that way, you could use `numbersList.AddRange({"1","7",etc})` or `New List(Of String) From {"1","7",etc}` or `New List(Of String)({"1","7",etc})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what part of this code you would like to make 'more sophisticated' but you can use Linq to return values

N.B Must make collection `asEnumerable()` to pick up extension method when names clash.

```
return numbersList.asEnumerable.Count(Function(v) v ="1")
```

Remember to import Linq namespace

```
imports System.Linq
```

Also, as Dmitry Bychenko  suggested (albeit in C# flavour), you could do this...

```
return "1762728381128911".Count(function(v) v = "1")
```

Comment: See update. It's no good copy/pasting this without understanding it. I suggest you research Linq. See here [LINQ .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

Comment: As-is, this code won't work ; `v.Equals("1")` will call the `Char.Equals (Object)` overload which will always return `false` if the arg isn't a `Char` and a `String` isn't a `Char` ; see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ojCJTy). Also regarding last part, `String` is a "collection" (it implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)`)